# Need advices on the topology of this mesh

Tags: topology

how can I improve the topology of this mesh?

It's just an exercise to improve my topology management.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your render is OK you can keep it as it is, there must be simpler topologies like this one:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the render has no problem, my intent was to maximize efficiency with a topology as clean as possible. Thanks for the pictures, I will go for it

Answer (score 1):

For hard surface modeling I wouldn't worry about keeping the faces as quads. I know some people will try to beat it in your head to keep it all quads, but if you have a non-deforming, flat face that is clean as an ngon, on a hard surface model it's fine. The key words are flat and non-deforming.